# Discounts via PayPal REST API?

Tags: paypal

I'm attempting to integrate PayPal with a registration system I'm working on, and I'd like to give them multi-line transaction descriptions. I looked through PayPal docs and I couldn't find anything about discounts. I tried to put it as an item, but PayPal won't except negative value items. Does anyone have any ideas or know what I could do? Might I be stuck making transaction information through a database on the registration system? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should run your discount business rules on your own website. Then redirect user to PayPal with an exact amount.

Comment: This question should never have been closed. It's not off-topic.